Change Chromium Extension Settings Programmatically
I've got an application deployed on kiosk hardware running on Chromium and using the Virtual Keyboard plugin to allow users to type in the application, as the kiosk has no physical keyboard, just a touchscreen.
I'd like to deploy an update to a kiosk remotely so that that the Virtual Keyboard either switches the language of the keyboard or at least exposes the option to the user to choose from among multiple available languages so they can pick it for themselves without opening the door to the whole chrome://extensions since I've gone to some trouble to prevent the user being able to interact with the browser outside of my application (hiding navbar, menubar, and so forth).
I've dug around on the web and using Chrome Dev Tools and discovered that the settings I want to manipulate are in fact in LocalStorage in the tree item chrome-extension://randomnumbersandlettershere. Is there any way for me to change these settings using software that I have written, either in my browser-hosted application at http://localhost (i.e. through javascript, I'm guessing not allowed because of cross-domain security issues), or using NodeJS running on the same computer as the Chromium instance?
Or is the only way to change these settings using the chrome://extensions user interface with a human-in-the-loop.

Use managed storage.

@woxxom I am not the author of the chrome extension... can you elaborate?

Then there's no other way.
